VS Code - C# - dotnet run doesnt find the file but I can open and edit them?
I am new to coding and today I have cleaned up my folder where I save all the files, seemingly did a mistake doing so because now I can not get any C#-file to run in VS Code and also cleared the recycle bin...
Maybe on of you have an idea how to fix this?
I have tried everything in my repertoir and it just does not want to work again.
The files all show up in the solution explorer and even the ones I create directly in VS Code just do not get recognized.
Thanks a lot in advance for taking a look into it! :)
This is what happens when I run the code
(clean [appdata roaming folder deletion]) re-installing  it multiple times didn't change that, neither re-installing the extensions nor changing to a different profile.
Creating files in VS Code works and also coding them, they just don't run.
Also created a project via the "dotnet new console -n test" and tried running that file(s) as well which resulted in build errors for the .projcs and the .cs was not found.
Edit:
Seems like also c-files are affected, like "Hello world" is running but anything more complex than that won't compile, it just loads forever.
What have I done to cause that? I was only deleting files from the folder where the projects are saved so it shouldn't be anything that critical?

It does not look like you have a csproj file. Without this, dotnet does not know what to run. Please run dotnet new console in your C# folder which will create a csproj file and a Program.cs. Write your code in the Program.cs file and run dotnet run in your C# folder.

Thanks a lot for your quick response!
This seemed to work and I think I get it now, so I always need to first "create" the .csproj file in the relevant folder for any file to work as the "dotnet run" pulls the information from that file so any that is not included in it will also not run?
It still seems a bit arcance to me. :D

It's weird because before I could simply create and run a .cs file anywhere in the solution explorer but now I can only run it throug the .csproj file and if I add another file into the folder it stops working. :/

Update: I have cleaned up the folder and redone the "dotnet new console" - now everything seems to work again. Seems like it took a few tries to rebuild all the deleted files. Thanks again for your help on that, it really drove me crazy hehe

Thanks, didn't know that! Done! :) PS: Somehow it works compiling the .cs file with "F5" compiler but it just won't find the files with the "dotnet run" command [Ctrl+Alt+N], only the .csproj, so I assume the issue is in the extension that uses it (code runner)?
